# Acceleo. One of the parameters' class couldn't be loaded for method

Tags: acceleo

When I invoke a java service with input string parameter I obtain the error **One of the parameters' class couldn't be loaded for method returnString(String) of class es.bancopopular.easy.toFast.varPosition.Sum.**. Another method in this java service without input parameter run ok, but I can't invoke correctly any method with input parameters
My java class is very simple:

```
package es.bancopopular.easy.toFast.varPosition;
public class Sum {

Integer result=0;
int resultInt=0;

public void initialize(){
    this.result = 0;
    this.resultInt=0;
}
public Integer getResult(){
    return ++result;
}
public int getResultInt(){
    return ++resultInt;
}
public int returnInt (int num){
    return num;
}
public Integer returnInteger (Integer num){
    return num;
}
public String returnString (String str){
    return str;
}
}
```

The query declaration is

```
[query public test(str:String) : String = 
invoke ('es.bancopopular.easy.toFast.varPosition.Sum',
        'returnString(String)', 
        Sequence{str}
        )
/]
```

And the invocation from template is

```
Returned text: [test('Hello world')/]
```

could anyone help with this code?
Any help will be appreciated

Thank's in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything seems to be correct instead of passing parameter to function.
Please pass the parameter with fully qualified type as follows:

```
[query public test(str:String) : String = 
invoke ('es.bancopopular.easy.toFast.varPosition.Sum',
        'returnString(java.lang.String)', 
        Sequence{str}
        )
/]
```

Hope this may help you.